# word boundaries in irb

Tags: ruby, macos, readline, irb, word-boundaries

I'm using Terminal on Snow Leopard.

At the command line, if I've typed `foo.bar.baz.bang.quuz.quux`, when i tap option-B, it moves the cursor backward word by word -- stopping at every period, because it considers a period to be a word boundary. Likewise, option-F moves forward word by word.

In irb (0.9.5, ruby 1.8.7), option-B and -F also have this behavior, but the period is no longer treated as a word boundary, which makes these keyboard shortcuts significantly less useful.

How can I change this?

EDIT: Curiouser and curiouser: On an EC2 instance which has the same irb and ruby versions, the period *is* treated as a word boundary.

Comment: FYI, Ruby 1.9.2 treats the period as a word boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be of relevance here?
http://jorgebernal.info/2009/11/18/fixing-snow-leopard-ruby-readline/

In any case make sure option-B/F are actually bound to forward and backward-word in your inputrc files, like John pointed out.

Also word boundaries are determined by your locale (see the "locale" command), and more specifically by LC_CTYPE (character classification). I don't think that's the problem here, but you might want to check out and compare your locale settings just in case.

Comment: jorgebernal.info's procedure did it. Thanks! Enjoy the bounty; don't spend it all in one place :)

Answer (score 4):

I think this has more to do with the Readline module.

The word break characters can be changed. Run this in your IRB and see what characters is Readline using:

```
Readline.basic_word_break_characters
```

Readline is part of the standard ruby library: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/readline/rdoc/index.html

Comment: Thanks for answering, but changing this value doesn't seem to affect the behavior at all. Also, on one of my EC2 instances, `Readline.basic_word_break_characters` doesn't contain `.`, but the word movement commands do stop at periods.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem with Ruby 1.9.3 on OS X Lion (10.7) and tried modifying `Readline.basic_word_break_characters`, but it made no difference either. Also, just like lawrence, on another machine with ruby 1.8.7, `Readline.basic_word_break_characters` doesn't contain period, but IRB still breaks on the `.` character, so I really have no clue what this setting has to do with IRB.

Answer (score 1):

Readline also uses the following configuration files:

- /etc/inputrc
- ~/.inputrc (or a filename specified by the environment variable INPUTRC)

This can cause different behavior on different machines (but probably not between ruby versions - I guess ruby adds another layer of configuration on top).