# IRB doesn't respect dot (.) as a word-break character

Tags: ruby, irb

I'm using irb on OS X, and when I press option left/right (or META+B/F) the cursor moves to the next/previous word. But irb doesn't wont to treat dot (.) character as a word separator.

I've tried to add the (.) to the .irbrc, so it looks like this now:

```
Readline.basic_word_break_characters = " \t\n`><=.;|&{("
```

But that has no effect.

I'm using the stock Mountain Lion ruby, and a manually compiled 1.9.3, both versions of irb behave similar. Also dot is treated as a separator in bash and in pry, so the system wide settings are probably fine.

Any help appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097919/word-boundaries-in-irb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, it seems that the problem was that there were no **libreadline** installed in my system at all. Installing the latest readline and recompiling ruby fixed the problem.

I've used readline 6.2 from `ftp://ftp.cwru.edu/pub/bash/readline-6.2.tar.gz`, which was installed used the basic `./configure && make && make install`.

And I've installed ruby 1.9.3-p194 using **ruby-build** with the following options

```
sudo ruby-build 1.9.3-p194 /opt/ruby-1.9.3-p194 CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-readline-dir=/usr/local"
```

After that IRB started treating dots, underscores and a bunch of other characters as word separators.

Also the properly working readline should return something like:

```
Readline::VERSION => "6.2"
```

and the misbehaving one says:

```
Readline::VERSION => "EditLine wrapper"
```

Comment: thanks, this worked for me. Combined with some information from (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7020698/835766) I was able to get this working under rvm as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble with the above (either it failed to install or you just need more instruction), here's what I did to make it work.

For those on latest Mac OS X (10.11.2 El Capitan):

`curl ftp://ftp.cwru.edu/pub/bash/readline-6.3.tar.gz > temp-readline.tar.gz` then unzip with `tar temp-readline.tar.gz`. Then go into that directory with `cd readline-6.3`. Configure and install with `./configure && make && make install`, just like above.

Hope this helps.